# mysql_query returning wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following code

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['FBID'] )   ) {
    $uid      = $_SESSION['FBID'];
    $sql      = "SELECT *, count(member_nr) AS notifyMe 
                 FROM poolWinners 
                 WHERE member_nr = '$uid'   AND notification ='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $notification = $row['notifyMe'];
    }//while
      if ( $notification > 0 ) {
        echo '<span class="badge">' . $notification . '</span>';
    } //if
    var_dump($notification);
} //isset( $_SESSION['FBID'] )
```

The above script returns how many notifications a member has as you can see in image below
[image]

**My Problem**

The script is returning the wrong result (wrong number of notifications). Have a look at the table below, the member number appears 3 times in the table so:
`$notification = $row['notifyMe']` Should = 3 AND NOT 1

What am I missing or doing wrong here? Thanks for reading

Comment: sum up the values in the notification column? as they look to be 1 for each, like this `select sumNot from poolWinners where member_nr = '$uid' AND notification = 1;` no need to loop over the results, get the sum straight

Comment: or do `select count(member_nr) from poolWinners where member_nr= '$uid' and notification = 1;` and use the count instead of the sum, to avoid `notification` values bigger than 1. again take the full value straight, no need to loop over the result set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$sql      = "SELECT *, count(*) AS notifyMe 
             FROM poolWinners 
             WHERE member_nr = '$uid'   AND notification ='1'";
```

Notice `count(*)` , it will fetch how many records are matching criteria.

And initialize `$notification = 0;` at the start.

Comment: Thanks mate but im getting same problem

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but I cant for the live of me figure out why but it is still returning one even with the edit which I thought would solve it, a var_dump confirms $notification value is  one (1)......any other suggestions

Comment: Define `$notification = 0` before while()

Comment: Same problem...:-( guess its back to the drawing board for me

Comment: Edit question and paste SQL for your table structure

Comment: Sorry mate this is a bit embarrising, im an idiot, had the wrong user id...thank you very much

Comment: I had to initialize `$notification = 0` aswell but other than that 1st solution was good

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried approaching it from this angle

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM poolWinners WHERE member_nr = '$uid'   AND notification ='1'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$notification = array();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $notification[] = $row['notifyMe'];
    }
//an array count on notification should give you the number of elements in the array i.e those that matched the query

$total_count = count($notification);
```

Comment: if you're dealing with a small amount of rows you could try mysql_num_rows to see how many rows were returned

Answer (score 1):

In your code the notification will be always one, since it will take only the notifyMe field of last  row in the result set.

If you want to get number of notifications, try this

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['FBID'] )   ) {
    $uid      = $_SESSION['FBID'];
    $sql      = "SELECT *, count(member_nr) AS notifyMe 
                 FROM poolWinners 
                 WHERE member_nr = '$uid'   AND notification ='1'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $notification = 0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
       $notification++; 
       /*
       OR $notification += $row['notifyMe'];
       */
    }//while
      if ( $notification > 0 ) {
        echo '<span class="badge">' . $notification . '</span>';
    } //if
    var_dump($notification);
} //isset( $_SESSION['FBID'] )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql      = "SELECT *  
             FROM poolWinners 
             WHERE member_nr = '$uid'   AND notification ='1'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
$notification = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM poolWinners WHERE member_nr = '$uid'   AND notification ='1'";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
echo "Toal notification".mysqli_num_rows($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```